# Why does my picklist field show Required when it is not marked as required?

Tags: visual-workflow

We are using the new Flow Designer, and in the designer, we have a picklist field that is not marked as required:

[image]

Yet, when we run the Flow, we get this:

[image]

Checking the XML, the XML shows the field is not required:

```
<fields>
    <name>Generational_Suffix</name>
    <choiceReferences>Select_Choice</choiceReferences>
    <choiceReferences>Generational_Suffix_Picklist_Choice</choiceReferences>
    <dataType>String</dataType>
    <defaultSelectedChoiceReference>Select_Choice</defaultSelectedChoiceReference>
    <fieldText>Generational Suffix</fieldText>
    <fieldType>DropdownBox</fieldType>
    <isRequired>false</isRequired>
</fields>
```

This happens on multiple browsers and computers.

The field is not required at the object level.

How can I force this field as not required?

Comment: Seems you may be experiencing Issue #1 in this [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5LcAAI).

Comment: can you check object schema, is it required at database level

Comment: @JayantDas I thought they have fixed this issue when they decided to ditch Flash based flow builder. Guess I was wrong. It contains same bugs as the predecessor.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I have never experienced it myself but looking around found this link. And amazingly this has been an issue for 4 years.